# iOS 6 Maps tutorial?

Tags: ios, dictionary, ios6, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I can't seem to find a decent tutorial to use a map in my iOS 6 app. I got the part of adding the MapView, but I want to add pins in custom locations. I want my pin to have a title, a subtitle and a picture on the left. I'm not sure if I need a custom pin of not for that. I also want a detail disclosure indicator to segue to another page. Should be that complicated, but I don't know where to start. Help please!

Comment: http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/804_Introduction_to_MapKit_Framework_for_iPhone_Development.aspx

Comment: The only problem in this tutorial is, how can you set the subtitle? Even in the examples it's not showed.

Comment: For further references: replace "subTitle" with "subtitle" everywhere. Probably a typo from the original author.

Answer (score 7):

There you go...a pretty good iOS6 Tutorial with the new MapKit.
Helped me a lot. Enjoy...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't explain how to fit a large title in the box.

Comment: Well, my frame is already the same width as my screen, so I don't think I can make it larger and anyway I'm not sure how to change the width. Maybe the solution is to change the font of the MKPinAnnotationView, but I don't how.

Comment: you can set and change the properties for UIFont and UILabel in a subclass of MKAnnotationView.